# XML task results to Sql Table in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In SSIS, I am feeding a XML file and using XSLT getting one resultant XML(with my required field) file.

Could I use the result of XML task  to directly feed the SQL table.

While exploring in this regard..i got to know I can save the result of XML task to a variable and can use this variable to put the data in SQL table.

Not sure how to accomplish this or is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the resultant value contained within a varaible. Assuming it is just one value. You could use a Parameterised Execute SQL Task to accomplish this.